# Get-ChildItem recursive that matches regex patterm and rename the item

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get child item recursively that have " (1)" and I want to remove this part. Here is where I got so far but it throws an error. Please help.

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where{$_.Name -Match "\s{1}\(1\)"} | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace ' \(1\)', ''}
```

Thank you

Comment: "throws an error" is not helpful in the least.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I have noticed it does work it does through is an error that file already exist I need to improve the script to make sure that it does prompt what to do with the existing file delete it or cancel renaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where{$_.Name -like "*(1)*"} | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace '\s*\(1\)', ''} -Verbose
```

It captures the (1) with and without leading whitespace and removes it.